# How to track django user details using zoho CRM

Tags: python, django, crm, zoho

How to track django user details using zoho CRM?

I am new zoho CRM, I got the few information and details how ZOHO CRm will be.

Now I want to know one thing, I had implement the django project and also have a account in zoho CRM. Now I would like to Tacke all my user details from app database in zoho crm.

how to export app database users to zoho CRM and how to track the user behaviour?

Comment: so this all you want is dump database and import that's it right ?

Comment: yes exactly i need to know

Answer (score 0):

Zoho CRM allow you to fetch contact information or push some data into CRM using their API.

Here is documentation about methods:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/api-methods.html

I think that you have to create automation to store user information in CRM on new user and get CRM record id from response and store it somewhere in your project. Using this id you can populate in CRM all activity related to this user.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `export django auth` but if `extender user model` is there then you can also take extended user model too...

Please update your question what Database you are using ?

Comment: In my project we are not have any django auth model, we just authenticating the user with facebook and allowing that user to access our app if he/she is authorized. What i need is, i need to store that user info(name, email etc.,) to zoho CRM(create a user with these details by calling api from django).

Comment: You didn't mention these details in question ! Anyway what social authentication model you are using ?